# How to retrieve the records that matches a part of the search?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I need to retrieve the records which matches a part of a searched value.

[image: The EventsAttended column of the records.]

**Description:**

The Column in the image above holds the Event IDs that the student attended.
All the events has a corresponding ID. In my VB code, I used the `Split()` function to split the `EventsAttended` column value with the delimiter "," and they will be put in an array.

**What I need**:

I need to know how I'm gonna use a query to retrieve a record by matching a part of my search. It has a very long value and a `WHERE` alone won't do the job because it represents exact value. But in my case, like for example, I want all the records that contains `77` in it thus It will return the rows 0,6 and 8 because they have the `77`. If let's say for example that I want all the records that contains `144` and `146` thus it will return the rows 6 and 8 only.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest not storing that delimited text in a single field but rather create another table that has one record per combination of student and event.  That will make the query you're asking for now very simple.  It's a false economy cramming data like that into one field.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did it just like that because for a purpose that did the job just fine. But, you're right I was thinking the same thing back then when I was figuring out how I will do it and I came out with this idea though it did the job but like you said it's not ideal but I'll stick on this one for now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like .... 
Assuming you want serch '77' try

```
select * 
from my table 
where EventsAttended like ('77,%') 
   or EventsAttended like ('%,77,%') 
   or EventsAttended like (',77%') ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this one later once I get home.

Comment: That last line should be `or EventsAttended like ('%,77')`.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney and _scaisEdge_, it works just how I wanted it like a charm! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Select * From YourTable Where "," & [EventsAttended] & "," Like "*," & [EventID] & ",*"
```

Extremely ineffective, so do listen to @jmcilhinney and redesign this from scratch.

Comment: Thank you I will try this one later. Yes I will redesign my system though I will reconstruct almost 80% of my code that relies on this delimited text field.